# What is the best way to make database calls via Generic Handlers in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to make database calls via Generic Handlers in ASP.NET?

I want to make database calls but am wary that the frequent connection and disconnection from the database in each request might cause performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry much about that since SQL Server uses connection pooling by default: [Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would also strongly advice you to have a look at an ORM like Entity Framework, if you haven't already. It will help you with the generic approach, among other useful things.

Comment: I am looking at a very basic and simple implementation so want to avoid using any ORM.

Comment: SQL Server still uses connection pooling even if you manage the connections yourself, and execute your home brew SQL statements on it.